# ERD for a simple bank system

Tags: sql-server, erd

I tried creating a simple erd for a banking system, I was wondering what can I improve, and where I did wrong. I'll also have to transfer this erd to sql and then try some queries on it. Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: @Eyeslandic I thought that connecting the Loan table to Account is better than connecting it to the Client so a client can only take a loan if he/she has an account in bank

Comment: @Eyeslandic and olimpiabaku I actually think a `Loan` is technically the same thing as an `Account` at a bank, from a business perspective. They're all just `Products` of the bank, whether it's a checking account, savings account, mortgage, personal loan, car loan, etc. They all get `AccountNumbers` tied to a specific `Client` and track an `Amount` that can change over time. But this gets into a little more complicated schema design then, so it just depends how you want to structure it.

Comment: Improve it how? Only you know precisely what you model and what your functional requirements are. Your design is very basic. There is really no way for anyone to suggest improvements except on the basis of experience. With such a model, experience will only lead into the very significant complexity that a "bank system" actually needs. One suggestion - stop prefacing the FK columns with the name of the associated table. That just adds clutter and effort. According to your ERD, a client can have only 1 account? That is very limiting.